# Vector Space coverage question

Tags: vector-spaces

So if you were given two distinct arbitrary vectors in 2 dimensional space does the vector space created by is possible for these two vectors cover the entire 2 dimension?

So in otherwords, can you create any given vector in that 2 dimensional space using combinations of the two arbitrary vectors.

Comment: What are your thoughts?

Comment: Consider our space as $\Bbb R^2$ and our two vectors given as $\begin{bmatrix}1\\0\end{bmatrix}$ and $\begin{bmatrix}2\\0\end{bmatrix}$.  Is the space spanned by these two-dimensional?  For a different example, consider our two vectors given as $\begin{bmatrix}1\\0\end{bmatrix}$ and $\begin{bmatrix}0\\1\end{bmatrix}$.  Is the space spanned by these two-dimensional?

Answer (score 0):

Take the standard basis of $\mathbb{F^2}$ $$I_2 = B = \begin{pmatrix}1&0 \\ 0&1 \end{pmatrix} \in \mathbb{F^2}$$

Then define the span of $B$ as : 
$$Span(B) = \{ a_1 \begin{pmatrix}1 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix} + a_2 \begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ 1 \end{pmatrix}, \forall a_1,a_2 \in \mathbb{F} \}$$

These are all the vectors on $\mathbb{F^2}$ spanned by basis $B$ (the set of all linear combinations).

Further reading: [Vector Spaces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_space#Basis_and_dimension) and [Linear Independence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_independence)